# Is there a way to change the return value of fn:path()?

Tags: xpath, xquery

Given a relatively simple snippet like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<doc>
   <h1>Irrelevant</h1>
   <item>
      <div>
         something
         <p>Not a target</p>
      </div>
   </item>
   <item>
      <h1>Relevant.</h1>
      <div>
         Location of relevant content
         <p>The target.</p>
      </div>
   </item>
</doc>
```

I'm interested in finding the path to the target node.  I can do this, for example:

```
//div[contains(.,"content")]/p/path()
```

The output is:

```
/Q{}doc[1]/Q{}item[2]/Q{}div[1]/Q{}p[1]
```

While it's probably helpful in other cases, in this particular case, the inclusion of the namespace uri of the target node name is not very informative.

I know I can forcibly strip `Q{uri}` by using `replace()`:

```
replace(//div[contains(.,"content")]/p/path(),"Q\{}","")
```

which outputs the path I want to see:

```
/doc[1]/item[2]/div[1]/p[1]
```

But it becomes cumbersome with multiple expressions.

Is there a way to suppress the inclusion of the namespace uri and receive only the local part of the node name? Absent that, is there another way/function (any version of xpath/xquery) to achieve the same result?

Comment: The format is intentionally as it will select with e.g. `Q{}doc[1]` the first `doc` child element in no namespace, independent of any namespace bindings set up in the host language like XQuery or XSLT or any binding done in the XPath API. If the function generated `doc[1]` and you used it  e.g. inside of XSLT code where the `xpath-default-namespace` has been set then you would not identify the element. As for simplifying the result, I don't think the W3C standard function has any option for that, you would need to check your particular XQuery or XPath processor.

Comment: Saxon PE and EE, for instance, have http://saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!functions/saxon/path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To roll your own function, in this example ignoring the namespaces, for instance, contrast

```
declare function local:step($node as node()) as xs:string {
  typeswitch($node)
    case element() return local-name($node) || '[' || (1 + count($node/preceding-sibling::*[node-name() = node-name($node)])) || ']'
    case text() return 'text()' || '[' || (1 + count($node/preceding-sibling::text())) || ']'
    case comment() return 'comment()' || '[' ||  (1 + count($node/preceding-sibling::comment())) || ']'
    case processing-instruction() return 'processing-instruction(' || node-name($node) || ')' || '[' || (1 + count($node/preceding-sibling::processing-instruction()[node-name() = node-name($node)]))|| ']'
    default return ''
};

declare function local:path($node as node()) as xs:string {
    string-join($node/ancestor-or-self::node()!local:step(.), '/')
};


//div[contains(.,"content")]/p/(path(), local:path(.))
```

https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/bdxZ8T

Comment: If you are to roll your own function, wouldn't something like this suffice? https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/bdxZ8T/1

Comment: Yes, if you rely on that function, yes, you don't need to construct the path. The way I have posted would work without relying on that function although I have used `||` and `!` in there which are 3.0 or 3.1 features. But you could replace them with `concat` or `for return`.